# Removing duplicates without overriding hashCode()

Tags: java, collections, guava

For *enterprise reasons* I can't override `hashCode` and I must use Java 6 (but I can use guava)

Whats the bests/simplest/quickest/most efficient/[insert indeterminate adjective equivalent to best] mechanism to remove duplicate beans from a Java collection?

A duplicate is defined by a subset of getters returning same values, e.g.

```
pojoA.getVal() == pojoB.getVal() && pojoA.getOtherVal() == pojoB.getOtherVal()
```

Comment: am I right that current hashCode does not reflect anything about equals of returned values by getter? How is it implement?

Comment: @sphinks yes hashcode is the defacto object

Comment: Write a `Comparator`?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom yeah probably and ...

Comment: Then add all elements in Set. It will add only one uniq element.

Comment: @sphinks set relies on hashcode, doesn't it ?

Comment: Extend the collection and override methods that actually compare the objects by hashCode? Is it possible?

Comment: @NimChimpsky if you are using TreeSet it will rely on comparator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the objects of interest into your own class, and override its `hashCode`/`equals` to pay attention to a specific subset of attributes. Make a hash set of wrappers, then harvest the objects from the set to get a duplicate-free subset.

Here is an example:

```
class ActualData {
    public String getAttr1();
    public String getAttr2();
    public String getAttr3();
    public String getAttr4();
}
```

Let's say you want to pay attention to attributes 1, 2, and 4. Then you can make a wrapper like this:

```
class Wrapper {
    private final ActualData data;
    public ActualData getData() {
        return data;
    }
    private final int hash;
    public Wrapper(ActualData data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.has = ... // Compute hash based on data's attr1, 2, and 4
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Wrapper)) return false;
        Wrapper other = (Wrapper)obj;
        return data.getAttr1().equals(other.getAttr1())
            && data.getAttr2().equals(other.getAttr2())
            && data.getAttr4().equals(other.getAttr4());
    }
}
```

Now you can make a `HashSet<Wrapper>`:

```
Set<Wrapper> set = new HashSet<>();
for (ActualData item : listWithDuplicates) {
    if (!set.add(new Wrapper(item))) {
        System.out.println("Item "+item+" was a duplicate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `new TreeSet<Pojo> (comparator)` with comparator implemented to reflect your condition (assuming integers here but replace as needed - for non comparable objects you need to find a hack to return some integer).

```
if (pojoA.getVal() != pojoB.getVal())
  return Integer.compare(pojoA.getVal(), pojoB.getVal());
if (pojoA.getOtherVal() != pojoB.getOtherVal())
  return Integer.compare(pojoA.getOtherVal(), pojoB.getOtherVal());
return 0;
```

Not as efficient as a plain HashSet though - @dasblikenlight suggestion is probably better.